# Slow ofMany relationship in Laravel for MariaDB

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, mariadb

### What I've got

I've a base model which looks like this :

```php
Schema::create('prospects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
});


class Prospect extends Model
{
    public function latestStep()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Step::class)
            ->ofMany([
                'date' => 'max',
                'id'   => 'max',
            ]);
    }
}
```

And a related one :

```php
Schema::create('steps', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('prospect_id')->constrained();
    $table->datetime('date');
});


class Step extends Model
{
}
```

When I want to retrieve `prospects` which has a `latestStep` I go like this :

```php
Prospect::whereHas('latestStep')->limit(10)->get();
```

The generated database request looks like this :

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `prospects`
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM `steps`
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT max(`steps`.`id`) AS `id_aggregate`, `steps`.`prospect_id`
        FROM `steps`
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT max(`steps`.`date`) AS `date_aggregate`, `steps`.`prospect_id`
            FROM `steps`
            GROUP BY `steps`.`prospect_id`
        ) AS `latestStep`
            ON `latestStep`.`date_aggregate` = `steps`.`date`
            AND `latestStep`.`prospect_id` = `steps`.`prospect_id`
        GROUP BY `steps`.`prospect_id`
    ) AS `latestStep`
        ON `latestStep`.`id_aggregate` = `steps`.`id`
        AND `latestStep`.`prospect_id` = `steps`.`prospect_id`
    WHERE `prospects`.`id` = `steps`.`prospect_id`
)
LIMIT 10
```

### The problem

On MySQL 5.7 it runs under 500ms for 20k prospects and 40k steps.

**BUT** on MariaDB 10.6 it takes between 2 to 3 **seconds**. If I increase the limit to 100, it takes about 20 to 30 seconds.

How can I solve this ? I've thought on putting an index there, but I don't really know on which columns.

Here are the `EXPLAIN` for MySQL
[image: EXPLAIN for MySQL]

And MariaDB
[image: EXPLAIN for MariaDB]

#### Edit 1

I've tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72121388/3789576 and the timing did not change.

Here is the corresponding EXPLAIN for MariaDB
[image: EXPLAIN for MariaDB]

Comment: Why do `whereHas('latestStep')` instead of just `whereHas('steps')`? `latestStep()` just returns a subset of `steps()` but is much more computationally intensive.

Comment: Hi and thanks for pointing it out. In the real use case, I add constraint on the latestStep like `whereHas('latestStep', fn($query) => $query->where(...))`. So I can't do it on `steps()`. I didn't put the full request because this simple already doesn't work properly.

Comment: I'd be curious to see what the difference is in the `EXPLAIN` output from the two databases. How well does a modern version of MySQL do?

Comment: @miken32 I've updated my question accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't wrap my head around the query, but here are some indexes that *might* help:

```
steps:  INDEX(prospect_id,  date)
steps:  INDEX(date, prospect_id,  id)
steps:  INDEX(prospect_id, id,  date)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

Also...  When you have `LIMIT 10` without `ORDER BY`, the Optimizer is free to pick *any* 10 rows.  Perhaps you would prefer the "latest" or something?

(PS:  Thanks for providing the generated SQL, the Create Table, and the Explains.)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply ! Should I test each indexes independently or mixed ? I’m aware about the limit issue, its only purpose here is to prevent the request from running for 6+hours 

Comment: I've tried all 3 indexes and nothing has change for the query time :/

Comment: I expected the first index to help with the innermost Select.  I was not sure if the others would help the rest.  Yes, I wanted you to add all of them (in a single Alter).  Did the Explain show that it was (or was not) using the new Indexes?  Did you also drop the redundant indexes?

Comment: The first time I've tried them separately, I've tried them all together now. See Edit 1 on my question for the EXPLAIN. I only kept your indexes and the PRIMARY one which is a unique on the `id` column